# Loop can't stop

Tags: c, windows, command

I'm trying to build a program which runs in command line written in C looks like that:

```
int main(void){

    char code[25];
    char *fullCmd;
    char *command;
    char *extraCmd;

    bool stop = false;
    int loop = 1;

    while (loop == 1){

        printf("C:\\>");
        scanf("%[^\n]",code);

        fullCmd = strdup(code);
        command = strtok(fullCmd, " ");
        extraCmd = strtok(NULL, " ");
        handStatement(code, command, extraCmd); 

        if(strcmp(command,"exit\n") == 0 || strcmp(command, "quit\n") == 0){
            loop = 0;
            printf("Program Terminated\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`HandStatement()` is one of my handles. But problems in here is that the while loop won't stop for me to enter another command when `handStatement()` is executed. If I don't use while, I can execute one command at a time.

Comment: Is message "Program Terminated" ever printed to the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need trailing `\n` characters in your `strcmp` call.

```
    if(strcmp(command,"exit") == 0 || strcmp(command, "quit") == 0){
        loop = 0;
        printf("Program Terminated\n");
    }
```

Also, you need to flush newline characters from stdin:

```
while (loop == 1){
    printf("C:\\>");
    scanf("%[^\n]",code);
    fullCmd = strdup(code);
    command = strtok(fullCmd, " ");
    extraCmd = strtok(NULL, " ");
    handStatement(code, command, extraCmd);
    if(strcmp(command,"exit") == 0 || strcmp(command, "quit") == 0){
        loop = 0;
        printf("Program Terminated\n");
    }
   /* Flush whitespace from stdin buffer */
   while(getchar() != '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the '\n' from your code, it will work. Unless your termination character has been changed, it will not actually place the newline character into the string and therefore your strcmp() will always return not equal.